# Is it more secure to spoof addresses using the HOSTS file?

Tags: windows, security, hacking

If I have a Windows service with a config file that points to web services it needs to call, is it more secure to put a fake DNS name for the server being connected to, then update the HOSTS file to redirect outbound calls to the right IP address?

Comment: What are you attempting to secure ?

Comment: I was just wondering about hiding the identity of the other servers within the network.

Comment: What's wrong with real DNS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, basically. Why would it be? If someone can read the DNS name from the config, then they can simply do a Ping or check the hosts file anyway.

Regardless, though, obscuring names and IP addresses is definitely not a way to do security and will simply make maintenance and management difficult for you.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Was just a random thought I had in the shower this morning...